# What are the best books for HTML, CSS, PHP, Javascript, etc

Tags: php, javascript, css

I decided want to aim my study to be a good web developer, learning stuff like Java EE and etc. But first, I would like to create a good base. Before creating advanced web systems, I would like to know how to create good websites, with the basics, like HTML, CSS, Javascript, PHP, patterns, design, structures.

So, what are the best books to learn it. I would like something with examples and exercises, like little projects. That's because I already tried to study this stuff, and without practice it's useless.

Thanks!

(OBS: I think that before going to Java EE, its good to be a good web designer, from the basics, right)

Comment: Sice today, i'm graduated in Computer Science, so, i know SQL, Java, and some good stuff. I'm not that noob lol.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  "Best" = Subjective. Please have a look at the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) and in particular the [Guidelines to Great Subjective Questions](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/) Recommend deleting this question and asking it again ticking the "community wiki" box (with your rep you can't edit and do that, unfortunately).

Comment: Web development != web design

Comment: @ajreal: *"google.com"* C'mon, recommendations from experienced peers are going to be about 18 times better than a blind search.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder: I think ajreal meant to learn with Google…

Comment: If you could do everything by googling then what is SO for?

Answer (score 5):

I am going to give you the specifications (PDF versions):

HTML: http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/html40.pdf.gz

CSS: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/css2.pdf

JavaScript: http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-262.pdf

If you want to be an advanced front-end developer, it is **essencial** that you become accustomed to these documents. They are all free and I recommend you to print them.

Note: There are more recent specs available (HTML5 and CSS3), but those are still working drafts. The ones that I listed above are still the most important publications in this area - they shall serve you as a base.

Also, note: These specs cannot be considered books, but they are nonetheless the best resources for HTML, CSS and JavaScript!

Answer (score 3):

Here are just a few of the books I've learned from in the past:

- *CSS The Missing Manual - David Sawyer McFarland*
- *Javascript The Missing Manual - David Sawyer McFarland* (should be titled jQuery the missing manual but does have a good introduction to javascript)
- *CSS Mastery - Andy Budd*
- *Web Standards Solutions* - Dan Cederholm
- *PHP 6 and MySQL 5* - Larry Ullman

Answer (score 2):

These books helped me a lot when I was starting out with Web Design.

1. Head First HTML with CSS & XHTML
2. Javascript: The Definitive Guide
3. CSS: The Definitive Guide
4. CSS: The Missing Manual
5. Learning jQuery

Answer (score 1):

For javascript I would suggest this great book
Beginning JavaScript 
[image]

Answer (score 1):

For HTML I definitely recommend *Designing With Web Standards* by Jeffrey Zeldman. For design patterns and usability there's no better book than *Don't Make Me Think* by Steve Krug

Comment: *DMMT* is indeed a nice book, but I don't think it's much technical…